# Regex for allowing semi colon

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex for validating a string but it doesn't accept semicolons? Is it because I have to use some escape sequences? I tested my regex [here](http://regexr.com/3e2ga) and it passes i.e allows semi-colon but doesn't allow in my c# app.

**EDITED** I have following regex

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[A-Za-z.&amp;0-9\s\\-]{0,21}$
```

And tried validating `sar232 trading inc;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: We're not going to go somewhere else to figure out what it is you're asking. The relevant information needs to be **here**, in the question itself. If it's off-site, and that off-site location is unavailable for some reason (off-line, moved, or whatever), your question has zero value to future readers. Please [edit] to include samples of text that should (and should not) match and the regex you're using (and the code that's trying to use it) that isn't working here in your question.

Comment: (`{1}` is superfluous.)

Comment: @ShizaKhan The different behaviours you're seeing is probably due to the `&amp;` bit: In one environment it's interpreted as an ampersand (where it is part of some XML), and in an other as five different characters in a class, one of them a semicolon.

Comment: Add a semicolon to the second character class: `^[A-Za-z0-9][;A-Za-z.&amp;0-9\s\\-]{0,21}$` - `&amp;` is most probably an ampersand  `&`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes works now.

Comment: Is it a value in some sort of XML? Please add more details to the question.

Answer (score 5):

The `&amp;` entity hints at the fact you have this regular expression inside some XML attribute, and that this `&amp;` gets parsed as a single `&` symbol when the pattern is sent to the regex engine.

That means, your pattern lacks the semi-colon inside the second character class, and that is why your regex does not match the string you provided.

The solution is simple: add the semi-colon to the 2nd character class:

```
someattr="^[A-Za-z0-9][;A-Za-z.&amp;0-9\s\\-]{0,21}$"
                       ^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexr.com/3e2gd)

Please also note that the `{1}` limiting quantifier is redundant since a `[A-Za-z0-9]` already matches only 1 symbol from the indicated ranges.